# Php Optimization: Fetching from database

Tags: php, html, database

I have some PHP code where once the next arrow is pressed it basically just gets the next image in the data base. However On mywebsite I sometimes can have over 600 users online all clicking next. Is there any way I can opimtize this php code to execute faster?

Thanks!

```
$nxtImage = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM images WHERE active=1 and id>$id and section=$section ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
$nxtrow = mysql_fetch_array($nxtImage);
$nxtnum = mysql_num_rows($nxtImage);
$nid = $nxtrow['id'];
$npicTitle = $nxtrow['img_title'];
$nimgLink = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $npicTitle);
$nimgLink = strtolower($nimgLink);
```

Comment: If `id` is some sort of index like a primary key, its already sorted so you don't have to tell it to sort anything. Removing this `ORDER BY id ASC` might already increase the performance of this query.

Comment: How about using something like Memcached to cache query results?

Comment: Despite the marginal speed advantage of mysql* functions, you should switch to mysqli* especially if that $id variable is declared anything like: $id = $_GET['id']...

Comment: What's your table structure? I.e. `DESC images;`

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I would do is change the query to this : `` SELECT `id`, `img_title` FROM images ... ``, to ensure that you're only grabbing what you need. The next thing I'd do is build a covered index on `id, img_title, section, active` so that it doesn't have to read off the data page.

Past that, get more hardware, :D

Comment: `SELECT * ...` is often faster though

Comment: @dualed, faster for who? The developer? Because that I would agree with, but it's not faster for the server. First off, `SELECT *` has to run an algorithm to recover all columns, and secondly, returning a more robust data set than what's needed will *never* be more efficient. Finally, when *not* using `SELECT *` you can build covered indexes, and that's where you really start seeing performance gains.

Comment: Faster as in "takes longer to execute on the SQL engine". Not sure if a covering index on 4 fields is a good thing or not, but it's probably the whole table anyway, from my point of view it is highly debatable to put an index on all columns of a table. Anyway, `*` should use a covering index if that index contains all columns of a table

Answer (score 3):

You could fetch all the images once in the beginning on the server side and then pass it to the client in Javascript (e.g. with JSON).

Then whenever a person clicks the arrow you just load the right image (e.g. with the next bigger array index) in Javascript.

This way you would eliminate a lot(maybe order by orders of magnitude) of database queries and thus improve your server performance.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know your users will be often clicking "next", you can implement [hashtag navigation](https://www.google.com/search?q=hashtag%20navigation), where the JavaScript is briefed with the parameters for the next 10, 20 images already, and performs the navigation using dynamic content, without bothering the PHP and MySQL so often.

Also, MySQL provides [tunning parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html) where you can increase the values of `key_buffer_size` and `table_cache` in order to tell your server to keep more information promptly available in memory for faster searches and immediate responses.

I usually tune it to use most of the unused memory on my server, because unused memory is a wasted resource.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column called nextID in your table. I know, it breaks DB normalization but in extreme cases, you may need these tricks to improve performance at the price of a field to maintain. Note that this new field could be maintained using a database trigger.